# What is the meaning of the theorem 2.5 in "Real and Complex analysis 3rd"?

Tags: general-topology

In the book "Real and Complex analysis 3rd" by Walter Rudin, Theorem 2.5 says that: "Suppose $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $K\subset X$,  $K$ is compact, and $p\in K^c$. Then there are open sets $U$ and $W$ such that $p\in U$, $K\subset W$, and $U \cap W = \emptyset$." 
But I think conclusion is true no matter whether $K$ is compact and $X$ is Hausdorff space.  And if I'm right, what's the meaning of this theorem?

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not right. First, as an example that "compact" is necessary, consider $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$. Then, $0 \in \mathbb{R} - (\mathbb{R} - \{0\})$, but any open subset containing $0$ must intersect $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ non-trivially. Next, "Hausdorff" is necessary. Let $V$ be the line with two origins, and let $K$ be any compact set containing one of the two origins. Then, $K$ and the second origin cannot be separated, as the two origins cannot be separated.

This theorem says, essentially, that if a point $p$ is not in a compact subset $K$ of a Hausdorff space, there is some degree of "closeness" such that that point is not "close" to that compact subset.

Comment: Why $0\in\Bbb{R}-\{0\}$ ? @DuncanRamage

Comment: Sorry, that should have been the complement of $\mathbb{R} - 0$; this has been corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Note that :

1. **$X$ is Hausdorff** $\implies $ given $k\in K$ and $p\in K^C$ we can find open set s $U_k,V_p$ such that $k\in U_k,p\in V_p$ and $U_k\cap V_p=\emptyset$.

So the collection $\{U_k:k\in K\}$ forms an open cover of $K$.

2.**Since $K$ is compact** every open cover has a finite subcover so $K\subset \cup_{i=1}^n U_i=U$.

Now consider $V_{p_i}$ corresponding to the above $U_i$ as chosen above and consider $p\in \cap V_{p_i}=V$.

Since finite intersection of open sets is open so is $V$.

Hence we get required $U,V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

**NOTE** that all the assumptions are necessary

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = \{0,1\}$ with the [Sierpiński space topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), with open sets

$\tag 1 \{\varnothing ,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$

Recall that every finite topological space is always compact.

Let $K = \{1\}$ and $p = 0$. Every open set containing $p$ is equal to $S$.

So Rudin does need $X$ to be Hausdorf.

The set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ is a subset of the Hausdorff space of $\mathbb R$ of real numbers. It is not compact and every open set about $\sqrt 2$ intersects $\mathbb Q$. So Rudin does indeed want both $X$ to be Hausdorf and $K$ to be compact.

Through the process of a [definitions <---> theorems <---> analysis/abstraction] cycle, mathematicians have found something interesting to say about topological spaces. You should take a deep breath before wondering if a math textbook contains superfluous hypotheses used to reach the conclusion in a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

It means that a compact set and a point not in that set can be
separated by open sets.  A crude example that you are not right
is a multipoint space S with the indiscrete topology, a point p
and any not empty set K without p.  Every subset of S is compact.